# RoR possible problems with a printer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm about to start development of an application with Ruby on Rails, which requires to print stuff, mostly tickets.

I'm guessing the printer I use won't have much impact.

So the question is, what are the different things I should take into consideration with the printing? I'm thinking a normal ruby program should have communication with a printer.

Comment: Are you going to be printing things on the server side, or having your users who visit the site print them on their printers? I'm guessing the latter, but clarifying that will get you more definitive answers.

Comment: I think I'm going to need to do both. The application's going to run on a local server, and I might have several printers scattered around the premises. I also have a workstation with it's own printer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most portable solution here is for your Rails application to emit a PDF and then hand that off to either the browser for rendering and printing, or to inject it into a local print spooler.

There are a number of ways to get PDF out of Ruby depending on your requirements. The easiest method is to render HTML and use a library to convert it to PDF like [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit). A method with more control is one where you draw out the document using a library like [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/).